# Doing aggregate functions on queries across standard and variant typed columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am looking to leverage the variant capabilities in snowflake. I am new to snowflake and can't see from the docs if it supports what I want to do. I want to perform queries on a table where I do aggregations (groupings) across columns that have standard types, (varchar, int ... ...) and values extracted from a variant column. My variant column will have store a collection of objects that look like:

```
{ "container": [
  {
    "param1": "value1a",
    "param2": "value2a",
    "param3": "value3a"
  },
  {
    "param1": "value1b",
    "param2": "value2b",
    "param3": "value3b"
  },
  {
    "param1": "value1c",
    "param2": "value2c",
    "param3": "value3c"
  }
]
}
```

In traditional sql schema to show what I am trying to do let's say i had a 1:n relationship where the container was a child on the many with a fk (parent_id) to specify the rel (say to parent). Here is a type of query i am trying to write on the variant column expressed in traditional sql/relational model:

```
SELECT P.column1, P.column2, C.param1, C.param2
FROM parent P
INNER JOIN Child c ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Could you add in an expected query result/output, please?

Comment: What have you tried, so far.  If nothing, I'd start by looking into the FLATTEN function of Snowflake.  It bursts out your arrays into records, which would mimic your 1:n relationship:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Comment: @DavidGarrison . yep sorry about that. My example variant data has a problem too. Let's say that param1 has a value that is the same across all three objects "value1a" and that param2 has a value, (value1b) that is the same across the first 2 objects. As someone else pointed out, my aggregate function is a simple count(1) as the_count.


```
column1, column2, param1, param2, the_count
----------------------------------------------------------------
siteX, pageY, value1a, value1b,2
siteA,pageB,value1a,value1b,1
siteC,pageC,value1a,value1c,1
```

Comment: uh. the formatting of the reply is bad news. new poster on this site. sorry David G.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) command, get access to the parts of your object.

Thus to access the three parameters of the `container` you would use

```
WITH input_tab AS (
  select PARSE_JSON('{ "container": [ {    "param1": "value1a",    "param2": "value2a",   "param3": "value3a"  },  {    "param1": "value1b",    "param2": "value2b",    "param3": "value3b"  },  {    "param1": "value1c",    "param2": "value2c",    "param3": "value3c"  }]}') as json
)
SELECT f.value:param1, 
    f.value:param2, 
    f.value:param3
    --,f.* -- here so you can see the other parts.
FROM input_tab AS i,
TABLE(flatten(input => i.json, path => 'container')) f;
```

Giving:

```
F.VALUE:PARAM1  F.VALUE:PARAM2  F.VALUE:PARAM3
"value1a"   "value2a"   "value3a"
"value1b"   "value2b"   "value3b"
"value1c"   "value2c"   "value3c"
```

which you will need to parse into there type data with the TRY_TO_x or AS_x casting functions.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, not sure which aggregate function you intend on using as you don't have it in your example and your values are strings, so your aggregate functions are limited.

#### Temp Table (for ease of use)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE X
AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON(COLUMN1) AS C1
FROM VALUES 
($$
{ "container": [
  {
    "param1": "value1a",
    "param2": "value2a",
    "param3": "value3a"
  },
  {
    "param1": "value1b",
    "param2": "value2b",
    "param3": "value3b"
  },
  {
    "param1": "value1c",
    "param2": "value2c",
    "param3": "value3c"
  }
]
}$$);
```

#### Option 1

```
SELECT C1
    ,F1.*
    ,F1.VALUE['param2']
FROM X
    ,LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => C1['container']) F1
;
```

#### Option 2

```
SELECT C1
    ,F1.*
    ,F2.*
FROM X
    ,LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => C1['container']) F1
    ,LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => F1.VALUE) F2
```